# Is the closure of $[\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2]$ in $B_3$ equal to the Borromean rings?

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory, braid-groups

Is the closure of $[\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2]\in B_3$ (the braid group with $3$ strings) equal to the Borromean rings? If yes, is there any simple proof?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Arguably the simplest proof.

Comment: Sounds correct! But is this "proof" considered acceptable in formal papers?

Comment: This is a 'hands-on' approach for convincing yourself it's true. I imagine it's quite difficult to convert this into something you can write down, let alone put in a paper. It also doesn't generalise because you obviously can't do the same thing if you have, say, 200 strands. On the other hand, it gives you an answer (you know that the braid closure IS exactly the Borromean rings) so you know you aren't wasting your time trying to prove a false result.

Comment: This might not be acceptable as "proof" but if you were to show each Reidemeister Move that took you from the braid to the usual picture of the Borromean rings, then yes, it would be a proof.  And indeed, there are papers where long sequences of pictures are proofs.